# How to convert this function/for loop into a list comprehensionor higher order function using python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

Hello all I wrote the following simple translator program using a function and for loops but am trying to understand list comprehension/higher order functions better. I have a very basic grasp of functions such as map and listcomprehensions, but don't know how to work with them when the loop requires a placeholder value such as place_holder in the below code. Also, any suggestions on what I can do better would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, you guys rock!

P.S how do you get that fancy formatting where my posted code looks like it does in notepad++?

```
    sweedish = {'merry': 'god', 'christmas': 'jul', 'and': 'och', 'happy':'nytt','year':'ar'}
    english =('merry christmas and happy new year')
    def translate(s):
        new = s.split() #split the string into a list 
        place_holder = [] #empty list to hold the translated word
        for item in new: #loop through each item in new 
            if item in sweedish: 
                place_holder.append(sweedish[item]) #if the item is found in sweedish, add the corresponding value to place_holder
        for item in place_holder: #only way I know how to print a list out with no brackets, ' or other such items. Do you know a better way?
            print(item, end=' ')
    translate(english)
```

edit to show chepner's answer and chisaku's formatting tips:

```
sweedish = {'merry': 'god', 'christmas': 'jul', 'and': 'och', 'happy':'nytt','year':'ar'}
english =('merry christmas and happy new year')
new = english.split()
print(' '.join([sweedish[item] for item in new if item in sweedish] ))
```

Comment: The fancy code highlighting is already there for your question but the correct syntax is any block of text indented with 4 spaces will be treated as a block of code and the syntax highlighter will be triggered on it when rendered.

Comment: i see it now, it wasn't showing up before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension simply builds a list all at once, rather than individually calling `append` to add items to the end inside a `for` loop.

```
place_holder = [ sweedish[item] for item in new if item in sweedish ]
```

The variable itself is unnecessary, since you can put the list comprehension directly in the for loop:

```
for item in [ sweedish[item] for item in new if item in sweedish ]:
```

Comment: simple, elegant and oh so effective. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner says, you can use a list comprehension to concisely build your new list of words translated from English to Swedish.

To access the dictionary, you might want to use swedish.get(word, 'null_value_placeholder'), so you don't get a KeyError if your English word isn't in the dictionary.

In my example, 'None' is the placeholder for English words without a translation in the dictionary. You could just use '' as a placeholder acknowledging that the gaps in the dictionary only provide an approximate translation.

```
swedish = {'merry': 'god', 'christmas': 'jul', 'and': 'och', 'happy':'nytt','year':'ar'}
english ='merry christmas and happy new year'

def translate(s):
    words = s.split()
    translation = [swedish.get(word, 'None') for word in words] 
    print ' '.join(translation)

translate(english)

>>>
god jul och nytt None ar
```

Alternatively, you can put a conditional expression in your list comprehension so the list comprehension only attempts to translate words that show up in the dictionary.

```
def translate(s):
    words = s.split()
    translation = [swedish[word] for word in words if word in swedish.keys()]
    print ' '.join(translation)

translate(english)

>>> 
god jul och nytt ar
```

The ' '.join(translation) function will convert your list of words to a string separated by ' '.

Comment: I like the usage of get and the formatting. Thanks for that, using ' '.join is far easier than the previous convoluted for loop.